# Can one route be active multiple times simultaneously? (non singleton controller)

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes, ember-router, outlet

I would like to create a sliding UI in Ember JS, where the view for newly entered route partially slides over the previous route's view. It has to be possible for a route to be active multiple times with different models. See the end of this post for an example.

I'm having trouble fitting this into the Ember routing and rendering system. [See this JSFiddle for what I've tried so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/6WV2U/1/) It basically links to a new panel route with a random ID.

I created a containerOutlet helper that renders a new view into a ContainerView instead of a regular OutletView. This works, but when entering the same 'panel' route, it doesn't create a new controller/view pair but just changes the model on the current one.

Would it be possible to instead instantiate a new controller/view pair and render it 'into' the ContainerView outlet?

It feels like Ember wasn't designed for this and I'm fighting the system, so any tips or clarification would be helpful.

---

**Example**

Spotify has done this quite tastefully in their [web player](http://play.spotify.com). I've attached a few screenshots to explain it better.

Basically when transitioning to a new route, it is rendered into a new 'layer' that slides over the previous route. Compare the [before image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FaWt.jpg) and [after image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDnU9.jpg).

The previous view is still there, and the application transitions back when a previous route is clicked. This can be repeated unlimited times to create a layered UI that retains a 'route' history.

---

**Code**

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route("panel", {
        path: "/:panel_id"
    });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        random = getRandomInt(1, 10);
        return { nextPanelId: random };
    }
});

App.PanelRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        random = getRandomInt(1, 10);
        return {
            id: params.panel_id,
            nextPanelId: random
        };
    }
});

Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('containerOutlet', function (property, options) {
    //(..)
    //Only this line has been changed
    return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, Ember.ContainerOutletView, options);
});

Ember.ContainerOutletView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    //For some reason it breaks when I remove this observer
    _currentViewWillChange: Ember.beforeObserver(function () {}, 'currentView'),

    _currentViewDidChange: Ember.observer(function () {
        this.pushObject(this.get('currentView'));
    }, 'currentView')
});
```